# In a MySQL table, is it equivalent to have two separate indexes on a column, or to combine them?

Tags: mysql, indexing

In other words, let's say this is my table:

**tbl_rel**

- id
- groupID
- created

**Index 1** on `id`

**Index 2** on `groupID`

OR

**Index 1** on `id` and `groupID`

I want to know if those are equivalent for any query involving the keys (see the queries below):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_rel WHERE id = 1
```

Does this use indexes in *either* of the index cases above?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_rel WHERE id = 1 AND groupID = 5
```

Does this use indexes in *either* of the index cases above?

Thanks all, it's been hard to find an answer on this.  I hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, btree indexes typically work left to right against the list of columns that make up that index to determine if they can be used by a query; so an index on id and groupid is an index first on the id, and then on the groupid. If the query doesn't use id in a query, then it won't be used because it can't work against the first column defined in the index.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_rel WHERE id = 1
```

Will use an index on id; or an index on id and groupid (if there isn't any index just on the id) even though groupid is included in the index but isn't part of the query; but won't even look at any index on just groupid.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_rel WHERE id = 1 AND groupID = 5
```

Will use an index on id and groupid if it exists (because both id and groupid are part of the WHERE clause); or an index on id (if there isn't any index on id and groupid); or will use an index on groupid if there is no index on id, and no index on id and groupid.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_rel WHERE groupID = 5
```

Will not use an index on id; or an index on id and groupid, because id is not part of the WHERE clause; but will use an index on groupid if it exists.

If there are several indexes that can be used for the query, then the database engine will normall try to identify the most appropriate index to use based on a set of "efficiency" rules... a reasonably good description is given [in this post](http://mattfleming.com/node/192)

MySQL supports either btree or hash indexes. It's worthwhile to read up on the differences between the two, and the situations where it is appropriate to use the different types. I don't believe MySQL supports binary indexes (even in its latest versions)

Comment: good explanation...  So in your 3rd case there (`WHERE groupID = 5`), with the two indexes I showed in my original post, I will have NO indexes matching the query - correct?  This makes me think that it is always best to do indexes on a single column, and create an index for any column that is using in queries (whether combined with other WHERE's or not) - is this standard practice?

Comment: @Shackrock - no, it isn't always best to have indexes on single columns... it all depends on the actual queries you're executing against the data. In your second SQL statement (using both id and groupid in the WHERE clause) an index on both id and groupid (or on both groupid and id) would be more efficient than indexes on either just id or just groupid.... MySQL will retrieve as many record entry details as it can via the indexes, but still has to read individual records from the database to test against conditions in the WHERE that can't be resolved by the indexes alone

Comment: Also just read that post - and it created another question: while id is 100% selective (every row is unique), groupID may be repeated (many id's can be in the same group) - but there is still an unlimited number of groupID possibilities.  groupID is still a good candidate for an index, correct?  Additionally: he says I can combine columns to create a more selective index - isn't this what I did in my 2nd example in the original post?

Comment: It's always best to have a UNIQUE INDEX on a primary key column, because this can also be used by INSERT and UPDATE to validate the uniqueness. Other indexes should always be decided (whether single-column or multi-column) by the SQL queries that you are executing in your code, or for the benefit of foreign-key constraints.

Comment: It would be more beneficial to have a second index on groupid and id, rather than on id and groupid... the latter is partly duplicating the index on id, so it simply forces MySQL to make a choice on which index to use when you use id in a WHERE clause; but an index on groupid then id would be useful for queries with just groupid in the WHERE clause, or with both id and groupid in the WHERE clause (because it provide an index that fulfils both parts of the WHERE clause from a single index)

Comment: Ok, I see.  So last clarification: If I have an index on groupID then id, do these 2 queries differ;  `WHERE id=1 and groupID=5`  ....  `WHERE groupID=5 and id=1`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7911/discussion-between-shackrock-and-mark-baker)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't matter about the order in the WHERE clause, MySQL has enough smarts to recognise that "WHERE id=1 AN|D groupID=5" and "WHERE groupID=5 AND id=1" are commutative (the order of the two parts doesn't matter)... but the order of columns in a multi-column index isn't commutative, it's hierarchical.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense to index uniquie Id column with another.

Index like this will produce unique indexes anyway. Look at this example:

```
Id GrId  Index_Id_GrId value (its pseudoindex, to show you how this work)
1   1     1
2   1     2   // new combination - new index value
3   1     3   // this index doesnt index second column for real
4   1     4
5   2     5
6   2     6   // every row have unique combination
```

New index is created when two columns combination changes. When one column always changes - you get unique anyway, you dont get better performance when you join by groupId.

Now lets say there are two non-unique columns.

```
Gr1 Gr2  IndexGr1Gr2 value (its pseudoindex, to show you how this work)
1   1     1
1   1     1  // same combination - same index value
2   1     2  // new combination - new index value
2   2     3 
2   2     3  
2   3     4
2   7     5
2   8     6
1   1     1  // combination from top again - same index value
2   2     3
```

Another words - new index is generated when new combination of data in indexed colums come.

In first case - you dont get better performance. In second case - yes, becasue index help "grouping" rows and find same combinations of values.

Sorry for my bad english, if i made some language mistakes.